# PostGIS TIGER geocoder not able to pinpoint hyphenated addresses

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I'm completely new to GIS in general, and I am trying to set up a geocoding system for some of my organization's data. So far I followed some [tutorials](https://experimentalcraft.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/how-to-make-a-postgis-tiger-geocoder-in-less-than-5-days/) to get the official PostGIS docker image working and ran the two TIGER loader scripts to download the nation and state (Hawaii) data from the Census Bureau site. Testing out some addresses with `SELECT * FROM geocode('[address]');`, it gets good performance and seems to work correctly, except for one issue: inputs with hyphenated address numbers seem to always return a street number of 0 and a rating of around 20.

For whatever reason, here in Hawaii we have a lot of neighborhoods with hyphenated address numbers. For example: '94-709 Kaaholo St, Waipahu, HI 96797'. The hyphen doesn't represent an address range, but a specific location. Whenever I try to run the geocoder on one of these, it's unable to pinpoint the specific location on the street and instead returns 0 for the address field and a lon/lat somewhere arbitrary on the street.

I've tried switching TIGER versions from RD18 to 2022, and I've tried editing the street number to remove the hyphen (like 94709 Kaaholo St, 94 Kaaholo St, or 709 Kaaholo St) but none of these seem to affect the output. It's as if the TIGER system just can't infer street numbers for these streets whatsoever. Streets without hyphenated addresses seem to work just fine, e.g. '900 S Beretania St., Honolulu, HI 96814' returns the right number/location.

Is this an issue with my setup, or a limitation of the TIGER system? In truth I don't need pinpoint accuracy for the work we're doing, so even getting a location somewhere on the street is probably good enough. It's just annoying, and I'm curious why this problem might be cropping up.

EDIT: for those of you who are running into the same issue, I brought up the problem to one of the developers and they created a ticket. https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5690

Comment: The Addresses work with the official census geocoder https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/tigerweb/ I expect it is a data standardization or just need a fuzzy sql statement. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241965/inconsistent-performance-using-the-tiger-geocoder

Comment: it looks as though the PostGIS geocode function automatically applies the normalize_address function to the text input, which converts the address to int4 and strips out the hyphenated portion. If the TIGER geocoder is expecting a hyphenated address for a given street, maybe it won't be able to locate it. Am I off track with this line of thinking?